# Referring to class method in parfor loop: significant memory usage

Tags: matlab, parfor

Example code of a class:

```
classdef testcls
    methods
        function sayhello(~)
            disp('Hello! ')
        end
    end 
end
```

and now if I call the method in `parfor` as below

```
A = testcls;
parfor ii = 1:4
    A.sayhello()
end
```

Mlint tells me a performance issue on the usage of `A` in the loop:

> The entire array or structure 'obj' is a broadcast variable. This might result in unnecessary communication overhead.

And I can suppress this message by using anonymous function:

```
A = testcls;
f = @A.sayhello;
parfor ii = 1:4
    f()
end
```

But my question is, will doing this help with the speed in anyway? Is there any better way to call a method in `parfor`?

Then, will the case get more complicated if I want to set up input/output arguments of the function?

```
classdef testcls
    methods
        function [out1,out2] = sayhello(~,n)
            out1 = (['Hello! ', num2str(n)]);
            out2 = n;
        end
    end
end

A = testcls;
f = @A.sayhello;
[a,b] = deal(cell(4,1));
parfor ii = 1:4
    [a{ii},b{ii}] = feval(f,ii);
end
```

---

EDIT:

I have observed significant resource consumption related to memory copy operations. Basically the job dispatcher will create an identical object for each worker, including all modified properties.

The `f = @A.sayhello;` usage does not save Matlab from memcpy-ing the entire object to every individual worker, even when the method itself does not call or store any class property.

I think this is the way to ensure transparency. However when the amount of data is huge this will become a big pain in the head.

Is there a way, instead of isolating the desired function into a standalone file-based function, of packaging `sayhello` in the object that will not invoke memcopying of the entire object?

---

EDIT: Thanks to @gnovice for the suggestive answer. I have made a test case in order to compare `parfor` with static method, `parfor` with non-static method, and serial execution using `arrayfun`.

Test case 1: `parfor` with non-static method (control)

[image: parfor non-static]

As can be seen in the memory usage record, the creation of a single object `testcls` uses ~700MB RAM, indicated by label `1`, which is followed by a `clear` command labeled as `2`, and the `parfor` loop runs above label `3`. The peak usage by `parfor` is approximately 4 times as a single object, while the pool has 4 workers.

Test case 2: `parfor` with static method

[image: parfor static]

The test procedure is done and labeled in the same way. From this evidence, the conclusion would be that only making the method static does not prevent the parpool from spawning identical objects for all workers.

Test case 3: Serial evaluation using `arrayfun`

[image: serial]

Since `arrayfun` performs a non-sequential serial batch evaluation, here is no reason for `arrayfun` to use more memory than needed by a single thread. Hence the evidence.

Example code:

```
classdef testcls
    properties
        D
    end
    methods (Static = false)
        function [out1,out2] = sayhello(~,n)
            out1 = (['Hello! ', num2str(n)]);
            out2 = n;
        end
    end
    methods
        function obj = testcls(~)
            obj.D = rand(1e8,1);
        end
    end
end
```

To run the test, use this script:

```
clear;clc;close all

A = testcls;
f = @A.sayhello;
parfor ii = 1:4
    feval(f,ii)
end
```

You may replace the `parfor` with `arrayfun` for serial validation.

Comment: Your last example code gives the error: "The sliced variable f must not refer to a function handle" - you have to use `feval(f, ii)` instead ([see here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/objects-and-handles-in-parfor-loops.html))

Comment: @whrrgarbl whoa you are right. My own code didn't have any argument but I thought it could work with one. I edit my code to the easiest case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For methods that don't have to reference any property of the class, it's probably best to make them [static methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html). From the documentation:

> Static methods are associated with a class, but not with specific instances of that class. These methods do not require an object of the class as an input argument, unlike ordinary methods which operate on specific objects of the class. You can call static methods without creating an object of the class

Since they can be called without having to create an object of that class, this should help you avoid the unnecessary duplication of the entire object across each worker.

Example method:

```
classdef testcls
  ...
  methods(Static)
    function sayhello
      disp('Hello!');
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

And to call it from each worker:

```
testcls.sayhello();
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I have run a comparison test and posted the results in the question. Unfortunately static methods do not eliminate identical object spawning. Please take a look at the snapshots.

Comment: @Yvon: Invoking the static method with `f = @A.sayhello;` may not work because it is still tied to an object `A`. I would retest the static method by invoking it without an object, just the class name: `f = @testcls.sayhello;`. I would expect different results for that.

Comment: You are right. Calling the static method by class name would avoid the unwanted spawning of identical objects. It works in this way, although, I lose the chance to access class-wide run-time parameters, because I cannot distinguish "data" (comes in large amount) from "parameters" (just a few numbers controlling the program running).

Comment: @Yvon: Perhaps one option is to store your run-time parameters as a class object unto themselves, then store an object of that class as a property in your larger data object. You can then access that property and broadcast the parameter object in your parfor loop instead of the larger data object.

Comment: hmm that sounds brilliant! just wanna put it here, that this would mean a complete re-design, literally specially designing the program in a more complex way solely for optimization, let alone the case when one has to make it compatible without parallel toolbox.